# Do I have the wrong Google font files?

Tags: css, svg, fonts

While it is common to use google fonts by linking to them on the Google servers, you can also load font files right on your site. This much I know. Previously, I have see web fonts installed in a "font" folder. The files were different formats, such as FrancoisOne-webfont.eot or FrancoisOne-webfont.svg. Recently, a graphic artist sent me a group of font files where each file is a style of the font, such as OpenSans-Bold.ttf. Are these the wrong files?

I can't seem to find any documentation in Google that addresses these files.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In order to use webfonts and have your site supported by all browsers, you will need fonts in different formats. Only ttf will not be enough AFAIK. The "bold" question is something different... some fonts come with their "bold" version (among others), that you'll need to specify as a different webfont and tell in your CSS that, for example, regular text is using webfont 1 (regular) while `strong` elements are using webfont 2 (bold one). The fonts that are coming in different variations usually have a better rendering than the extrapolated "bold" result

Comment: That's what I thought! But finding where to download the other formats only puts me into an endless loop of going to a basic informational page and the page where they just want you to use the API. The actual download is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

You can include fonts with

```
@font-face { font-family: 'myfont';
             src: url('path/to/yourfont.ttf') format('truetype'); }
```

and then use it like:

```
.classname {
     font-family: 'myfont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think that part of my problem is getting the path right in a CMS.